# object property undefined, One line after being console.log()'d

Tags: javascript, object, typeerror

I am trying to draw a table and form to add data to said table on a page, based on a json object retrieved from the server. I am getting a Uncaught typeError and cannot figure out why.

If I console.log() the object, It prints out in the console as expected. I can even output specific properties no problem. But when I try and use any of the properties, In a html sting, I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'formName' of undefined"

```
function testFunc(subform){
    console.log(subForm.layout.formName); //<--- prints the name to the console

    var form = '<div class="assetSubForm"><h2>' + subForm.layout.formName + '</h2>';
    console.log(form); //<--- error's out???

    return form;
}
```

The object is as follows:

```
{records: false, layout: {…}}
layout:
    fields: (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
    formID: 30
    formName: "Part 11 - Building Clearance And Fire Appliances"
    position: 120
    __proto__: Object
records: false
__proto__: Object
```

I can't for the life of me wrap my head around why. I have tried googling it but have come up empty as I can't figure out how to word it in an appropriate search term and all the results that do come up relate to scope or spelling errors (eg. object defined in anonymous function and referenced outside).

Comment: the `subform` parameter is not `subForm` as in the code. I guess is a typo you made copying the code, but it's worth checking.

Comment: @Sergeon you beat me to this comment by 3 secs. +1 to you

Comment: Most certainly unrelated to your actual problem: JS identifiers are case-sensitive, within `testFunc`you refer to `subForm` which is *not* the instantiated formal parameter `subform`.

Comment: @sergeon  and collapser You are both spot on, not sure how I missed it, Guess i've been staring at the screen to long. The weird thing is, that is exactly how i have it in my code, but console.log() does not seem to care about case

Comment: Don't you have a global (or "global enough", enveloping `testFunc`'s scope) variable `subForm`? Or an HTML element with `id="subForm"`, maybe (which would amount to the same thing)?

Comment: @mbojko nope. Not at all.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument name is `subform`, you refer to `subForm` in other parts of the code. 
I'm assuming there is a `subForm` variable visible in that scope, but its value changes, so depending on when you call the function it sometimes does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You are taking argument as `subform` but you are trying to access `subForm` in `console.log`

see line 1 and line 2 of your code.